# Launch web browser from application

Tags: android, browser

I'm trying to open default browser in Android from an application's dialog with a specific url. I use a personal dialog class, with a public method to insert clickeable text:

```
public class PictureInfoView extends Dialog {
private Context mContext;

public PictureInfoView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    ....
}
public void addSource(final String newSource) {
    TextView t = new TextView(mContext);
    t.setClickable(true);
    t.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            dismiss();
            try{
            Intent viewIntent = new Intent("Intent.ACTION_VIEW",
                    Uri.parse( "http://www.google.com" ));
            mContext.startActivity(viewIntent);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("CC", "PictureInfoView: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    v.addView(t, 0);
}
...
}
```

But when the text is clicked, an exception is gerenerated with this message:

```
"No activity found to handle Intent { act=Intent.ACTION_VIEW dat=http://www.google.com }"
```

Where is the problem?

Thanks for all! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent("Intent.ACTION_VIEW",
                Uri.parse( "http://www.google.com" ));
```

should look like

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse( "http://www.google.com" ));
```

Or use "android.intent.action.VIEW" (thats the String from Intent.ACTION_VIEW, [see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW))

Answer (score 0):

By chance, have you not included uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" in your manifest?